# How is standard error calculated

Tags: standard-error

[image]
The formulae doesn’t pass the common sense test. If the sample size n is as large as population size N, then obviously standard error would be zero, as every sample mean would equal exactly the population mean. (Assuming my understanding of standard error is correct: it is the standard deviation of the distribution of the sample mean)But the formula quoted above  obviously does not equal 0 when sample size equals population size.

I would really appreciate if some one can help a poor guy who is trying to teach himself statistics with no one to turn to for help!

Comment: You need to consider that a finite population, completely sampled, is not the same as an infinite population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is true only for infinite populations. For finite populations, there exist correction factors that tend to 0 if $n$ approaches $N$, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error).